# Mongoose referencing parent in embedded document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am fairly new to mongoose so bear with me a little. I have the following two simple schemas defined.

```
var ShipmentSchema = new Schema({
    shipmentId: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        required: 'Please fill Shipment Id',
        trim: true
    },
    dateInvoiced: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    vendorInvoices:
    [
        {
            referenceNo: {type: Schema.ObjectId,ref: 'VenderInvoice'}
        }
    ],
});

mongoose.model('Shipment', ShipmentSchema);

var VendorInvoiceSchema = new Schema({
    type: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    },
    referenceNo: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    },
    cases: {
        type: Number,
        required: 'Please fill in number of cases',
    },
    dateShipped: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    invoicedProducts:
    [
        {
            productId: {type: Schema.ObjectId,ref: 'Shoe'},
        }
    ]
});

mongoose.model('VenderInvoice', VendorInvoiceSchema);
```

If I want to get a list of VendorInvoices and want to include the shipment that they belong to is there any way to do so? I know how to get a shipment and its nested list of invoices, but if I wanted to go the other direction is there a way? Or do I need to normalize in this case?

Thank you

Comment: Include Shipment *inside* VendorInvoice? Couldn't you just find *Shipments* that have your desired VendorInvoices? (and then populate). With something like this: `Shipment.find({vendorInvoices:{$in:arrayContainingVendorInvoicesIds}}).populate('vendorInvoices')`

Comment: I think I might not be explaining this the best.. let's say for example I want to present a table that has every VendorInvoice listed. In that table, I might want to include a link to the complete shipment that the invoice comes as one of the columns. Is there any way that I can do `VendorInvoice.find().populateParentId()`?

Comment: No, there's no way to populate a parent, you can only populate children. One obvious reason for this I could see is that children don't have any information about who their parents might be, only parents do.

Comment: You're still thinking in relational db language, there are no tables in Mongodb, only documents and collections of documents. With `VendorInvoice.find` you'll get **documents** of VendorInvoices. (think (array of) JSON objects, very much like the how you've defined it in your schema). You can *present* that data in a tabular form, but that's another thing. Now as you have your schemas defined as: **Shipments** ***contains*** **VendorInvoices**, so the best you can get to achieve your goal is you get all Shipments that contain your desired VendorInvoices. Or..

Comment: You'll probably have to do multiple queries, finding VendorInvoices and then finding their parent Shipments. The only difference would, and the reason you should do this, would be that now you don't have to worry about Shipments's children VendorInvoices, which may have been duplicated oherwise, i.e. two Shipments containing same set of VendorInvoices. If that's not an issue then it's almost essentially the same as getting Shipments (with population).

Comment: Yeah I am definitely having a hard time breaking my traditional thinking, although in the case of last comment I was referring to table and link being html table and anchor elements, and the columnt being a visual column there. I think to do this (the way I have my schema set up) the best way would be to get all shipments (`Shipemnt.find()`), and then loop through each one and display each of its invoices. Thanks for your yelp (and patience!), if you want to put your explanation in an answer I'd be happy to accept it